# Unconditionally convergence of trigonometric systems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$
\text { If } 0<b<1
$,then I want to show this series$
f(x)=b \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\langle f, e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\rangle e^{2 \pi i b n x}
$ converges undoncitially in $L^2[0,1]$. My idea so far is to use that $
\left\{e_{n}=e^{2 \pi i n x}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \text { is a basis in } L^{2}[0,1]
$ so the bijection $
x \mapsto \frac{1}{b} x
$ will give this series convergence in $L^2[0,1]$. However, $
\left\{e_{n}=e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}
$ is not a orthonormal set in $L^2[0,1]$ so I can't say this series converges undoncitially. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about $f$? Also, is "unconditional convergence" the same as "absolute convergence"?